# Zebra thermal printer for browser printing

Tags: printer, mobile-phone, point-of-sale

I would like to know if exists a Zebra thermal printer suitable for browser printing.
I'm looking for something like the TM "i" (intelligent) Epson series, in that case, the printer is reachable by the browser using the local network and exchanging Http messages.

That solution was really nice because let be usable by almost all devices with a browser (phone, tablets) and not only by a computer of a custom app.

Do you know if exists some Zebra printer for this purpose?

Comment: Are you looking for a printer that supports [Internet Printing Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol) or something that has a custom website/GUI running from the device directly?

Comment: I would like to print some custom raw printer commands (for example ZPL code) from a website page.

Comment: The printer itself doesn't need to have this feature. Have you considered using an ethernet print server? Or a standalone PC (or Raspberry Pi) running a web printing server?

Comment: I need to handle native commands, I think a "standard" print server would be suitable for PCL/PS drivers and not for native commands. For example I need to manage the status request command to get the printer status, this is possible only using native commands and bidirectional connection like tcp, serial, or virtualcom over USB.

Comment: Does [this driver](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/mac-linux-or-unix-driver-suggestions-for-zebra-printers.html) expose the functionality you need? [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/) is a unix print server that provides an HTTP GUI. At the very least this should work on a Raspberry Pi, although I wouldn't be surprised if there are "standard" print servers running CUPS with this driver included. I'm not sure if the CUPS gui allows you to send ZPL to the printer directly though.

Comment: If CUPS can also ready printer status it can fit my requirements, but usually all print drivers works only one way. I'll try to get some info about cups and reading from printer. Thanks